# Can't use glht post-hoc with repeated measures ANOVA in R?

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

I have a data frame with this structure:

```
'data.frame':   39 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ topic   : Factor w/ 13 levels "Acido Folico",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 3 levels "Both","Preconception",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : int  14 1 36 17 5 9 19 9 19 25 ...
```

and I want to test the effect value ~ variable, considering that observation are grouped in topics. So I thought to use a repeated measure ANOVA, where "variable" is considered as a repeatead measure on every topic.
the call is `aov(value ~ variable + Error(topic/variable))`.

Up to this everything's ok.

Then I wanted to perform a post-hoc test with `glht(model, linfct= mcp(variable = 'Tukey'))`, but I receive two errors:

> ‘glht’ does not support objects of class ‘aovlist’
>   no ‘model.matrix’ method for ‘model’ found! Since, taking out the error term solve the error I suppose that is the problem.

So, how can I perform a post-hoc test over a repeated measure anova?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing an appropriate statistical method, and not about a specific programming question.

Comment: funny, a similar question was deemed off topic on CrossValidated and moved here! Anyway, this is not about theory but about the implementation of glht()

Comment: It was unclear to me if your question is about specifically getting the `glht` function to work, or if there is any statistically valid method to run post-hoc tests over repeated measure anova. If the question is just about `glht`, then please edit your question to include a complete [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Actually any model made with aov and containing an Error term, produce this error in glht.